# express bodyParser fail my json

Tags: json, node.js, express, body-parser

I send POST request with axios to my nodejs server

```
axios.post(config.SERVER_URL + 'getData', 
{
    id: '1234'
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**Data**

> {"id":"1234"}

**Chrome Network**
[image]

bodyParser fail my object, so i receive it like this

```
{ '"id":"1234"}': '' }
```

**NodeJS code**

```
app.post('/getData', function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });

    console.log(req.body);
    res.end(JSON.stringify({ data: 'hello'}));
});
```

**Console**
[image]

Tryed to reinstall bodyParser and express, doesn't help.
I use it like this

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Just don't get why it happens.

Comment: you really want to show more code. Like a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve)

Comment: thank you, i updated my thread

Comment: that is not all your node.js code - can you show the minimal necessary code to reproduce this please? starting at `express = require('express')` and ending at `app.listen`? Just showing a `post` handler and two loose `app.use` does not tell us when you specify what, and what else you've added that might interfere with body parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be sending `form-urlencoded` data  in your request. Try setting the headers to tell express you're sending `application/json`

```
  axios({
     method: 'post',
     url: config.SERVER_URL + 'getData',
     data: { id: '1234' },
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```